# Please help me to solve this surface integral question.

Tags: integration, vectors, vector-fields

I'm trying to solve this but my answer was wrong every time. The question is:

> If $\vec{F} = 2y\hat{i} - 3\hat{\jmath} + x^2\hat{k}$ and $S$ is the
>   surface of the parabolic cylinder $y^2 = 8x$ in the first octant
>   bounded by the planes $y = 4$ and $z = 6$, then evaluate
>   $$\iint_S\vec{F}\cdot\hat{n}\ dS.$$

Correct answer is : 132

I've tried to integrate by taking the projection of the surface  $y^2 = 8x$ in $yz$ plane, where I've taken $\hat{n} = \hat{i}$ as unit normal to $yz$ plane.

Comment: What have you tried? This question will get closed in minutes if you don't add your working.

Comment: Explain what have you tried so far, what is your result(s) and what is the assumed correct answer.

Comment: Include your work. We aren't magicians.

Comment: Well, there's your mistake (for starters). The normal has to be the normal to the *surface*, so it most definitely will not be $\hat i$. As I said, include your work. Let's see the parametrization, how you do the computation (once you repair the normal problem).

Comment: But the projection of surface to y-z plane will have the normal $\hat{i}$ ?

Comment: @TechVision But you need the normal *to the surface*, not the normal to the plane on which you're projecting!

Comment: Earlier I've done that, by taking the normal to the surface but the $\hat{k}$ component of unit normal was zero hence $\hat{n}.\hat{k}$ = 0 and according to $dS = \frac{dxdy}{\hat{n}.\hat{k}}\$ denominator will be zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrize your surface, say by:

$$\vec r(u,v):=\left(\frac{u^2}8\,,\,\,u\,,\,\,v\right)\;,\;\;0\le u\le 4\;,\;\;0\le v\le 6\;\implies$$

$$\vec{r'_u}=\left(\frac u4\,,\,\,1\,,\,\,0\right)\;,\;\;\vec{r_v'}=(0,0,1)\implies\vec{r'_y}\times\vec{r'_v}=\begin{vmatrix}\vec i&\vec j&\vec k\\\frac u4&1&0\\0&0&1\end{vmatrix}=\left(1,\,-\frac u4\,,\,\,0\right)$$

Then, since $\;\vec n=\frac{\vec{r'_y}\times\vec{r'_v}}{\left\|\vec{r'_y}\times\vec{r'_v}\right\|}\;$ ( and observe that the norm of the vectorial product cancels in the following!) and also $\; F(\vec r(u,v))=\left(2u\,,\,\,-3\,,\,\,\frac{u^4}{64}\right)\;$
,  we get that:

$$\iint_s\vec F\cdot\vec n\;d\vec S=\iint_D\vec F(\vec r(u,v))\cdot\left(\vec{r'_y}\times\vec{r'_v}\right) dA=\int_0^4\int_0^6\left(2u\,,\,-3\,,\,\frac{u^4}{64}\right)\cdot\left(1\,,\,-\frac u4\,,\,\,0\right)\,dA=$$

$$=\int_0^4\int_0^6\frac{11}4u\,dv\,du=\frac{66}4\int_0^4u\,du=\frac{33}4\cdot16=132$$

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your help and time. Now I'm totally understanding where i was doing wrong.